# Using a single DOM Content Loaded call

Tags: javascript

What would be the right approach to use a single DOMContentLoaded call on multiple functions as shown below:

Here is what I have:

```
function rtd3Transaction() {
        if (rtd3tchanged.checked || rtd3dchanged.checked) {
            formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = '';
            formWrapperConfirm.required = true;
        } else {
            formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = 'none'
            formWrapperConfirm.required = false;
        }
}
rtd3tchanged.addEventListener('change', rtd3Transaction);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtd3Transaction);
rtd3Transaction();

function rtd3Device() {
        if (rtd3tchanged.checked || rtd3dchanged.checked) {
            formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = '';
            formWrapperConfirm.required = true;
        } else {
            formWrapperCertainSelection.style.display = 'none'
            formWrapperConfirm.required = false;
        }
}
rtd3dchanged.addEventListener('change', rtd3Device);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtd3Device);
rtd3Device();
```

Comment: Make a method that calls the other methods?

Comment: function start() {
    handler();
}
window.onload = start;

I guess I can remove the `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'` line and pop the methods inside that function.

Comment: @SLE - I wouldn't recommend it. The `load` event on `window` happens **very** late in the page load process, after all dependencies have been loaded (all images, stylesheets, etc.). `DOMContentLoaded` happens rather earlier, once the parsing of the main HTML is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the input @T.J.Crowder, I will just pop the functions within one eventListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to do it the way you have it now. You can attach multiple handlers to the event, they'll all get called.

If you want to change it, though, you can do it the same way you do any other time you want to do multiple things at once from a single place: you put the operations in a function, and arrange for that function to be called:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    rtd3Transaction();
    rtd3Device();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create an array that I can push new initialization routines onto wherever they're defined, then initialize each once the content-load event fires.

```
const initRoutines = []

function example1() {}
initRoutines.push(example1)

function example2() {}
initRoutines.push(example2)

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  initRoutines.forEach(routine => routine())
})
```